# Replace object in json with angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to replace an object with another object, using the `angular.forEach` function:

```
angular.forEach(agenda,function(evt){

    if(evt.identifiant  == event.identifiant){

        evt = event;
    }

});
```

For some reason the object `evt` doesn't get replaced by the `event` object inside my `agenda` array. Both `evt` and `event` are correct JSON objects (calendars events).

I wonder if my syntax is correct, or if I should do this another way?

**EDIT:**

This code is working, but it is not what I want, as it is changing only a value inside my `evt` object:

```
angular.forEach(agenda,function(evt){

    if(evt.identifiant  == event.identifiant){

        evt.start = event.start;
    }
});
```

Comment: Easier if you pass in the index as well. Then you can agenda[index] = event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you'll want to update the `angenda` object itself by assigning the filtered `event` to the current `key` that corresponds to `evt`  like so:

```
/* The iteration handler on forEach provides access to the key of the current value */
angular.forEach(agenda,function(evt, key){

    if(evt.identifiant == event.identifiant){

        /* Assign/update the value for current key of agenda like so */
        agenda[key] = event;
    }
});
```

For more information on `angular.forEach` [see the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) - hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(agenda,function(evt, index){

    if(evt.identifiant  == event.identifiant){

        agenda[index] = event;
    }

});
```